# Is it possible to change CSS dynamically? in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, css, laravel

Is it possible to change CSS dynamically?

I want to apply `class=sheet padding-top: 28mm;` when the size of $anArray is less than 30.
When this array is more than 30 then `padding-top: 28 * 2 mm;`
and when this array is more than 60  `padding-top: 28 * 3 mm;`

Do I have to make

```css
.sheet2 {
    padding-top: 56mm;
}
.sheet3 {
    padding-top: 84mm;
}
```

And change the class selector by Javascript?

I would like to use a smarter way.  :(

```html
<section class="sheet">
    {{ $anArray }}
    if(anArray)
```

**another.css**

```css
.sheet {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    page-break-after: always;
    padding-top: 28mm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure not to override the `padding-top: 28mm;` so try this:

```php
@php
    $anArraySize = count($anArray);
@endphp

<section class="sheet" style="padding-top: {{ 
    ($anArraySize < 30) ? '28mm' : 
    ($anArraySize < 60) ? '56mm' : 
        '84mm';
}}">
```

You can apply the same logic for class inclusion:

```css
.pt-28 {
    padding-top: 28mm;
}
.pt-56 {
    padding-top: 56mm;
}
.pt-84 {
    padding-top: 84mm;
}
```

```php
@php
    $anArraySize = count($anArray);
@endphp

<section class="sheet {{ 
    ($anArraySize < 30) ? 'pt-28' : 
    ($anArraySize < 60) ? 'pt-56' : 
        'pt-84';
}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this

Define one class and add your required css

```
.pt-28 {
   padding-top:28mm;
}
```

Now in your blade you can do like this

```
<section class="sheet {{ count($anArray) < 30 ? 'pt-28' : '' }}">
```

OR

```
<section class="sheet @if(count($anArray) < 30) pt-28 @endif">
```

Or you can directly add inline css like this if you want

```
<section class="sheet" style="padding-top:{{ count($anArray) < 30 ? '28mm' : '' }}">
```

Comment: You are not considering the cases for less than 60 and more than 60.